# In java, Is there a way to be notified when data becomes available on a stream or pipe

Tags: java, io

I want to be able to have a thread wait for data on one or more streams/pipes to be available and then poll-read the data ( and then wait again for more )

```
InputStream is = process.getInputStream() // stdout of process
is.setOnDataAvailable((stream)-> {
     readerThread.signal ... // tell thread to wake up or put worker task in queue
});

// reader thread
dataAvailable = true; // start assuming data there.
for(;;) {

    if(!dataAvailable) {
       waitForSignal();
    }
    dataAvailable = false;
    for(allINputs) {
       if(input.dataAvailable()) {
           read it and do something
           dataAvailable = true; // might be more check inputs again
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that Java Future can handle your use case https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: The inputstream is a block stream yet,it means the read operation will be blocked until the data is valid.so why you want to do above thing?

Comment: @jeanr Looks like Java future is most likely a "wrapper" API written to manage tasks in processes and threads so it really provides no performance advantage (fewer threads etc) over manually creating processes and threads to read streams, but it might be a convenient way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Java IO API is a blocking implementation. In other words, if you have a thread with a loop that looks like:

```
byte[] input = ...;
while (stream.read(input) != -1)
{
    ...
}
```

Then that thread will block until there is something to read from the stream (or the stream closes, there's no more data, etc.), which from description sounds like you what you want to do.

Furthermore, from your code it looks like you want read process output. Make sure you drain the other streams from the process as well (like stderr) or you'll exceed the limit and get an exception.

Comment: alas likely true and when given pipes created by spawned processes and the like one is probably stuck with what you get as one can't create and manage new types of streams like "channels" which do have these asynchronous API features.